# if statement problem

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I wanna have an if statement that's condition is "when a float ivar is BETWEEN two numbers" something happens.

How can I do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode or iPhone (I've retagged it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float value=0.0;

```
if(value<=maxValue&&value>=minValue)
{
      //do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if ((your_number > lower_number) && (your_number < higher_number))
     //do something...
```